# Storing Credit Card information using PayPal Payments Advanced API?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I want to use PayPal Payment Advanced API to store the customer's credit card info on the PayPal's website the first time the customer enters the credit card info. For subsequent customer visits, i want to retrieve the Credit Card info from the PayPal's server. Is this possible? What does the PayPal server return me ( like a transaction id )that I can store in my database for that customer and then use it for subsequent requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for Paypal payments advanced. From their *[tutorials](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/paypal-payments-advanced/)*:

```
PayPal Payments Advanced requires use of PayPal's hosted checkout template...
```

This means that you have to use their hosted pages (you can probably do so using an iframe if you want). The reason for that is that in order to collect credit-card details you have to be [*PCI compliant*](http://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-basics.php), meaning, you have to pass a series of security checks/tests. This process took my company almost two years and major development (and other) resources, so you probably don't want to go down that path.

Comment: let's say i use the hosted pages solutions.even in this case how can i make sure the customer doesnt have to enter everytime.so will the PayPal server return me a transaction id that i can use in future transactions?

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/

Comment: yes.that's correct.thanks for pointing it out to me.i remember having seen this earlier but couldnt find in the Payments Advanced documentation. i guess i will have to see if this is part of Payments Advanced as well